# NHibernate 2.1 xml mapping like a join

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to join two tables in NHibernate 2.1 with the xml mapping.

The parent class (Table1) has a property that is a List of the other class (Table2).

Now class1 has two properties that I want two join with class2.

These are the tables I tried to simplify for this example:

[image]

So class1 should be like:

```
public class class1{
    public IList<class2> Class2Items{ get; set;}
}
```

Like I said, this is a simplified example, so I don't want to mirror the properties from class2 to class1. I want a List of class2 elements in class1.
The join would be for 'Type' and 'Number'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bag:

```
<class name="Class1" 
      table="Table1">

   <bag name="Items" cascade="all">
      <key column="FK_to_table1"/>
      <one-to-many 
         class="Class2"/>
   </bag>
</class>
```

more info on that topic can be found [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have no foreign key to the other table. The only thing is I want that type and number should be the same. But type and number are not keys. Something like select * from table1 t1 join table2 ON t1.Type = t2.Type where t1.Number = t2.Number